# Setting SPI chip select every few bytes with buffered read

Tags: spi

I managed to successfuly read packets from MCP3208 ADC using SPI on Raspberry Pi - I can do that both with `spidev.h` library or with WiringPi.

The problem is that when I want much higher speed, I can preload - say - 1000 queries into an array (each query is 3 bytes) and fire it all up at once with wiringPiSPIDataRW function. In theory I should get 1000 samples as fast as possible, but unfortunately it doesn't work like that.

According to the datasheet, before each read (query) I need to set up chip select to high for at least one clock cycle. Unfortunately I don't seem to have any control over the chip select pin while the read/write sequence is fired, so the question is - is there some mode that will fire the chip select every n bytes?

Or if not, what other fast ways are there to read data from SPI?

Without reading multiple bytes in a single read/write sequence, it gets pretty slow - about 60kHz and I need more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both wiringPi and spidev will be using the underlying Linux SPI driver.

At a guess you are using the Pi3B as other Pi models will probably top out at 20ksps.

My [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) and the [bcm2835](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/) library use their own driver which will probably allow much higher sample rates.

For a metric see http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/faq.html#How_fast_is_SPI

Comment: Does it mean that when I call a single read in a loop it will be much faster than the equivalent with Linux SPI driver? Thanks a lot for the link - I've been looking for something like this for a long time and I found nothing! From the plots I can see that the speed is almost the same as with linux spi driver at 3 bytes per sample and 2MHz

Comment: I have not tested multiple SPI requests with the kernel driver.  There is a `spi.cs_change` field in the C IOCTL.  Perhaps edit the wiringPi source `wiringPiSPI.c` and change the value to 1 and then rebuild the library. That might then toggle the chip select at each transaction.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how is the cs_change executed? If I have spi.len of 128 bits and set bits per word to 16, will it turn CS on and off every 16 bits being transferred? That is exactly what I would want to achieve.

Comment: You need to look at the spi_ioc_transfer structure.  Each member is one SPI transaction.  The cs_change will presumably set the CS change around that transaction.  You pass an array of those structures to the SPI transfer.  If this is not how you/wiringPi are handling multiple transactions then I've wasted your time (although it's quite easy to write your own version in C, wiringPi is a thin wrapper around the SPI driver).

Comment: This seems to solve my problem quite exactly! Thank you a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: @MaxWalczak I'd be interested to know what throughput improvement you can manage with that change.  It could be significant or irrelevant depending on how the driver works.